# Insert duplicate ID into column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a comment table and to test things out, it has three fields.

- ID (null not allowed and auto increments) int
- OriginalCommentID (null not allowed) int
- Comment (null not allowed) nvarchar(50)

For my purpose, OriginalCommentID is an afterthought as to how comments would be edited, but as comments seem to show, maybe it's a bad idea to implement this since it might confuse future developers or at least me in the future.

```
INSERT [Comments]
(
    OriginalCommentID
    ,Comment
)
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED.ID
VALUES
(
    INSERTED.ID
    ,@Comment
)
```

On this embedded Sql, I keep getting "Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'"

EDIT:
This is my test table.  Same error.

```
INSERT [test]
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OriginalCommentID, INSERTED.Comment
        INTO test2
VALUES (OriginalCommentID, Comment);
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me. Are you trying to insert a new comment that is a reply to a previous comment? Or you want to get the `CommentID` after insertion.

Comment: The column is an afterthought, for when someone edits the comment, but I want to keep the edit comment history.  In this case, the INSERTED.ID can't be null, but it is a new comment.

Comment: Even with the "clarification" this just doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you need to step back and explain what you are trying to do. Are you trying to maintain a CommentHistory table or something like that?

Comment: The `INSERTED.ID` is only available ***AFTER*** the `INSERT` operation has completed - you **cannot** use that notation to insert a value into the table in the first place ....

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the INTO part of the SQL. You need to output into another table. Try something like this.

```
INSERT [Comments]
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OriginalCommentID, INSERTED.Comment
        INTO MyTable
VALUES (OriginalCommentID, Comment);
```

Comment: What is the name of the table you are trying to insert into and what are the column names and data types?

Comment: See my edit on my question.  For this Q and A, the table name is test and test2.